# ASP.NET MVC - Extending Ajax.ActionLink method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there anywhere I can see the method definition of the current Ajax.ActionLink method as I'd like to be able to extend it with a custom method but not sure on its current method definition

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
public static class AjaxExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this AjaxHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText,
        string action,
        string controller,
        object routeValues,
        AjaxOptions ajaxoptions,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
            anchor.InnerHtml = linkText;
            anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
            anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But obviously I need to add the AjaxOptions stuff which the default Ajax.ActionLink contains, but I'm not sure on what it's definition looks like.

The reason for doing this is that I want the linkText to be an HtmlString as I want to do something like so: `@Ajax.MyActionLink("<span class="highlight">Hello</span> World",...)`

Second Edit:

I get a compilation error now:

```
...does not contain a definition for 'MyActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'MyProject.Helpers.AjaxExtensions.MyActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper, System.Web.HtmlString, string, object, System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions)' has some invalid arguments
```

Here is my Extension Method:

```
public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
        HtmlString linkText,
        string action,
        object routeValues,
        AjaxOptions ajaxoptions
    )
        {
            return MyActionLink(ajaxHelper, linkText, action, routeValues, ajaxoptions);
        }
```

Here is how I use it:

```
@Ajax.MyActionLink(@Html.Raw(item.ITEMID.Replace((string)ViewData["ID"], "<span class='highlighted'>" + (string)ViewData["ID"] + "</span>")), "MoreDetails", new { id = item.ITEMID }, new AjaxOptions()
                       {
                           UpdateTargetId = "MoreDetails-" + item.ITEMID,
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                       })
```

Third Edit:

I changed my Extension method:

```
public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
            this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
            IHtmlString linkText,
            string action,
            object routeValues,
            AjaxOptions ajaxoptions
        )
            {
                return MyActionLink(ajaxHelper, linkText, action, routeValues, ajaxoptions);
            }
```

and now I get the following error:

```
Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state. System.Collections.IDictionary
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by using the solution found here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1702210/4518688.aspx/1?Re+Quick+question+about+Ajax+ActionLink+and+span

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72551#266442